# Error in plugin gulp-sass when running gulp styles

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

Sass error I am receiving when I run "gulp styles"

**Current versions:**
npm -v 8.11.0
node -v 16.16.0

**Computer specs:**
macOS Monterey 12.2.1
**Processor:**
3.3 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i5

```
username@unknown1234 understrap-child % gulp styles
[11:19:51] Using gulpfile ~/PhpstormProjects/54321/wp-content/themes/understrap-child/gulpfile.js
[11:19:51] Starting 'styles'...
[11:19:51] Starting 'sass'...
Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:
    
gulp-sass no longer has a default Sass compiler; please set one yourself.
Both the "sass" and "node-sass" packages are permitted.
For example, in your gulpfile:

  const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

[11:19:51] The following tasks did not complete: styles, sass
[11:19:51] Did you forget to signal async completion?
```

I can seem to figure out how to fix this issue. Ran different commands from npm install, npm install --save-dev sass, npm install sass and npm install gulp-sass.

[Here is the screenshot of the error in PHPStorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqoKt.png)

Comment: Did you include the line of code suggested in the error?  Otherwise show your gulpfile.js.

Comment: When placing the const sass = require line of code into gulpfile.js, it breaks all gulp commands. I have written the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a solution to fix this issue.

**First; I checked what node was linked.**

```
$ Brew search node
```

**Second I need to connect node v16 so that @14, @16, and node were checked**

```
$ brew install node@16
            
$ brew link node@16
```

Once you are done, make sure node @14, @16, and node are checkmarks so that it is active. [View node packages checked in PHPStorm »](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU69j.png)

**Third I search what NPM packages were checked.**

```
$ Brew search npm
        
$ brew install nfpm  
        
$ brew link nfpm
```

Make sure npm, nvm and nfpm are checked. [View NPM packages checked in PHPStorm »](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCVG5.png)

Then I ran `lando rebuild`

Lastly, I ran `NPM install`.

**Here is the version I am running on my Imac:**

• Npm -v 6.14.17

• Node -v v14.20.0

Afterward, Gulp Styles worked correctly. I hope this helps everyone out there who runs into this issue. Good luck :)

Thx, [MJMDesignz.com](https://MJMDesignz.com)